# Accordion Menu Reaches Past Parent Div Height

Tags: css, height, accordion

I don't exactly know how to phrase this so I'll just do the best I can. Here is a JSFiddle of a webpage I am working on for my company:

http://jsfiddle.net/hzkem4zx/

```
#divMain{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#divFAQ{
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-height: 500px;
}
#divTopics{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 500px;
}
#ulTopics{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 500px;
}
#ulTopics > li{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: URL("http://i.imgur.com/FVKGcnj.png");
    line-height: 54px;
    min-height: 54px;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#ulTopics input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
#ulTopics li .FAQList{
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
#ulTopics li input:checked ~ .FAQList{
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

It contains an accordion menu using checkboxes. The only problem is after extending the entire menu, the parent div's height reaches only accommodate for the top of the last element with a height set. So if the last element with a height is the list that drops down, the container div reaches to the TOP of that, but it does not extend to reach past the bottom of it.

What I'm trying to do is get any solutions that will make it so the container div reaches past the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing is caused by your #divTopics

```
#divTopics{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px; //pushes 50px down
    left: 50px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

change the 'top' to a 'margin-top' and you should be ok.

Comment: I'd upvote you but I need 15 rep. margin-top fixed it but created a white bar above it. I tried padding-top and that worked! Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasFries If the answer solves your problem, you should be able to mark it as correct even without any rep points.